# XHTML Strict is not valid because of html tags inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml, tags, validation, strict

I'm creating a site using XHTML Strict markup. Inside the html I need to put a js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { $('#nav li#nav-strona-glowna').append('<a href="/platinium/" class="hover active"><span>Strona glowna</span></a>');

</script>
```

Unfortunately the xhtml is no longer valid, because of an "" tag inside this script. How can I validate xhtml without removing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You want a CDATA tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents#Using_CDATA_Instead_of_Comments) The example stolen from that MDC page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  var i = 0;

  while  (++i < 10)
  {
    // ...
  }
 //]]>
</script>
```

In general it's better to avoid the issue by having your JS (and CSS) in external files.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function () { $('#nav li#nav-strona-glowna').append('<a href="/platinium/" class="hover active"><span>Strona glowna</span></a>');
  ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[CDATA Wrapper](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

```
 <script>
 //<![CDATA[

 // js goes here - bypasses browser HTML parser

 //]]>
 </script>
```

I suggest that you find ways to inject HTML in your page that doesn't directly involve writing HTML markup in your JavaScript.  Your relationship with your web designer will be much stronger, more cooperative, and fruitful if you keep your content, presentation, and behavior separated.

But for those cases where that is not possible, a CDATA wrapper will prevent the browser from parsing your JavaScript as HTML.

Keep in mind that there is a reason they call it HTML Strict.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

There's a problem in your code, which is that it's missing a close brace and parenthesis. Possibly a typo?

Regarding the XHTML validation, the best option is to put you JavaScript in a separate file. Failing that, add a CDATA section around your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () { $('#nav li#nav-strona-glowna').append('<a href="/platinium/" class="hover active"><span>Strona glowna</span></a>'); });
//]]>
</script>
```

Note that the JavaScript comments are there for browsers such as IE which do not parse XHTML as XML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents

Comment: This is correct, which is exactly why I always prefer plain HTML.

Comment: the problem is I've tried all those solutions, but none of these works, the problem still appers, 

i can't put the js in separate file becouse its content is generated by php

Comment: @David: What precisely is the problem? What have you used to validate your XHTML?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
// your code
]]></script>
```

Should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

What error does validator gives you exactly?  The code you posted looks pretty valid.

Btw. If you don't need XHTML for some very specific reason,

(http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/serving-xhtml-as-xml/)

you're probably better off with just HTML4 or HTML5, which you can also make valid code with.

Comment: alright, I have this site on local server so I can't put a link, anyway I use a ff addon that validates code wchih must have a bug, becouse I put all the source to http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and it validates like charm :D thanx for answers